# How to use function in JavaScript to convert temperature

Tags: javascript, html

I want to build code which convert Temp from Celcius to Fahrenheit by using any Function in Java Script
I am wondering how to take the value from window.prompt and use it for further converting temperature by any functions in JavaScript?

I Created HTML and now in JavaScript I wrote window.prompt where i can put the value. But I can't figure out how to take this value from window.prompt and convert it to Fahrenheit  by using function.

```js
var button = document.getElementById('greeter-button');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  Temperature = window.prompt('What is temperature in celcius?');
});
```

```html
<div id="button_and_text">
  <button id="greeter-button">Button!</button>
  <br> Click the button! Check the temperature!
  <br><br>
</div>

<div id="greeter-output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean this?
Note you would normally need to convert the string returned from the prompt to a number, for example by using +temperature, but the multiplication casts the string to a number for you. Also the operator precedence helps here

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // on page load
  var button = document.getElementById('greeter-button'),
      output = document.getElementById('greeter-output');
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var temperature = window.prompt('What is temperature in celcius?');
    if (temperature != null) {
      output.innerHTML = temperature + "&deg;F = " + 
       (temperature * 9 / 5 + 32)    + "&deg;C";
    }  
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="button_and_text">
 <button id="greeter-button">Button!</button><br/> 
 Click the button! Check the temperature!
</div>

<div id="greeter-output"></div>
```

Comment: _"How to make the homework of someone that hasn't shown any research efforts..."_

Comment: @Andreas he was close enough

Answer (score 1):

The conversion formula is more important and once you get that then convert it to number and use `innerHTML`

```js
let button = document.getElementById('greeter-button');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let temp = +window.prompt('What is temperature in celcius?');
  let f = ((9 * temp) / 5) + 32;
  document.getElementById('greeter-output').innerHTML = f
});
```

```html
<div id="button_and_text">
  <button id="greeter-button">Button!</button>
  <br> Click the button! Check the temperature!
  <br><br>
</div>

<div id="greeter-output"></div>
```

Comment: @mplungjan here is my analysis of `Beat you..mins`. When i opened the snippet to write the answer,you answer was not there. Assuming you was already writing the answer in snippet , but SO does not gives any indication if any one is in process of writing the answer . So at that point no way i am aware that an answer is soon to follow. Secondly the time difference is calculated from the time the answer is posted. The diff is 2 mins and in this 2 mins the stack snippet was opened in my view again SO dint notified me that an answer has been posted. 
So delete answer after spending 2 mins in it?

Comment: Don't take it so seriously!